# Update form field value dynamically

Tags: extjs

I need to update the form field value using javascript as below:

```
var frmRec = App.frmEdit.getRecord();
frmRec.set('CallingName', 'Tesing calling name');
```

When I check the form data via the console, I can see the calling name field is updated:

```
console.log('rec: ', App.frmEdit.getRecord());
```

But the textfield in the form is not updated, old values still show up in the form. How can I "refresh" the value of the TextField in this case ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data binding is setup correctly there is no need to refresh anything.  The Extjs form supports two-way binding change to the record would be reflected in the text field and any change to the text field would be updated in the record.

[two way binding example](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/examples/kitchensink/?modern#binding-two-way)

The kitchen sink examples have lots of data binding examples.